# Using internal pulldown to pull esp8266 logic pin low

Tags: microcontroller, motor, switches, pullup

I'm trying to design a linear actuator with limit switches that both deactivate the motor drive and also signal my micro-controller that the switch is active. I plan on using a [DRV8871](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf) motor controller with an [esp8266](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) MCU and SPDT limit switches. My plan is to connect the pwm output to NC, the DRV8871 to COM and the limit active input pin to NO. The DRV8871 states that there is an internal 100k pulldown on the inputs, so if I use something like a 10M pull up on the limit active pin this should successfully pull the pin low to signal the limit is active (as well as disconnecting the pwm output from the DRV input). *What are some potential issues I may run into with design / would it work at all?*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Nixx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

notes / secondary questions:

- This entire setup is duplicated for each drive direction so reversing the motor away from the limit switch is not an issue.
- I'm trying to convince the guy I'm prototyping for that the design is decent enough to buy the components and try it out (which is why I haven't just tried it myself yet)
- would it perhaps be better to instead (or additionally) use a lower value external pull down on the DRV module so that I don't need such a high value pull up?

Comment: And what switch are you using? Current in motor? Limit switches are typically low current devices...

Comment: You can add a better schematic by editing your question and clicking the schematic button.

Comment: @awjlogan The switch is not switching the motor current, just the pwm signal to the H bridge controller.

Comment: you are attempting to use a mechanical solution to a programming problem

Comment: @Aaron OK - that's a bit clearer. But I agree with jsotola - better to handle this in software.

Comment: at least use the switch to activate a `disable` signal, do not use it to switch a drive signal

Comment: which pin is the `DRV IN` signal?

Comment: hopefully schematic is clearer. My goal is to have a software implementation as well, but to protect against potential software errors / crashes with a physical disconnect.

Comment: @jsotola slight added complexity aside, that's exactly my question.. for what reasons would this design not perform well?

Comment: i looked at the DRV8871 datasheet .... it appears that you are using the mode described in section `7.4.1 PWM With Current Regulation` .... in that case, it should work, but in one direction only .... look at `Table 1` .... you use PWM to switch between line 2 and 4, or between 3 and 4 .... in one direction, the PWM signal is on pin `IN1` ... in the other direction it is on pin `IN2`